# ReactJS: How do you swap elements in an array contained inside of an object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to swap the indexes of two elements inside of an array, which is contained inside an object as a property. In my CodeSandbox example below, whenever I try to click on the second "^" button, it gives me the error `TypeError: arr.container.map is not a function`. I've tried changing the object property containing the array by creating a function that swaps the indexes and I have also tried to use the splice array function to swap them as well. But no matter what, I keep getting the same error.

A demonstration of the error I'm getting can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cohen-rj399q?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState({container: [{num: 0}, {num: 1}]})

  return (
    <div>
      {arr.container.map((element, index) => (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setArr(arr => {
            return {
              ...arr,
              ["container"]: () => {
                let copy = [...arr.container];

                const temp = copy[index];
                copy[index] = copy[(index - 1)];
                copy[(index - 1)] = temp;

                return [...copy];
              }
            }
          })}>^</button>
          <p>{ element.num }</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your buttons `onClick`:

```
      <button onClick={() => setArr(arr => {
        return {
          ...arr,
          ["container"]: () => {
            let copy = [...arr.container];

            const temp = copy[index];
            copy[index] = copy[(index - 1)];
            copy[(index - 1)] = temp;

            return [...copy];
          }
        }
      })}>^</button>
```

you are setting `arr` to an object whose `container` property is a function. And functions don't have a `map` property.

I'm not sure why you felt you needed a function here. You're already using the functional form of `setArr`, so you can do this manipulation in the body of that function. It might end up looking something like this:

```
      <button onClick={() => setArr(arr => {
        let copy = [...arr.container];
        const temp = copy[index];
        copy[index] = copy[(index - 1)];
        copy[(index - 1)] = temp;

        return {
          ...arr,
          container: copy
        }
      })}>^</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response, for some reason I was under the impression that you couldn't alter the value of an object property with a separate variable containing the array with the swapped elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function like this:

```
const swapper = (index) => {
 let copy = [...arr.container];

 if(index === 0) {
   const temp = copy[index];
   copy[index] = copy[copy.length - 1];
   copy[copy.length - 1] = temp;
 } else {
   const temp = copy[index];
   copy[index] = copy[index - 1];
   copy[index - 1] = temp;
 }

  return [...copy];
}
```

Now, use it like this:

```
<button
    onClick={() =>
      setArr((arr) => {
        return (
          {
            ...arr,
            "container": swapper(index)
          }
        )
      })
    }
>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: instead of creating a function swapper, you can even use anonymous functions and call it directing in the container field

Comment: That's what I tried but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. I may have gotten the syntax wrong but I wasn't sure how.